# Configuring the SubLime HTML Linter Plugin to use latest html-tidy

Tags: html, macos, sublimetext2

Console output:
SublimeLinter: htmltidy activated: /usr/bin/tidy

I’ve installed the tidy --head via brew and my PATH is set to export usr/local/bin.
Any ideas on how to active tidy within usr/local/bin/tidy?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I found was to add the correct path to SublimeLinter preferences:

```
"paths": {
    "linux": [],
    "osx": [
        "/usr/local/bin/tidy"
    ],
    "windows": []
},
```